# r filter based on two columns and not missing

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataset with multiple rows per id for some ids not all like this

```
    Id    Date       Col2   Col3    Col4
    1     2011-09-08 Red    NA      NA
    2     2010-07-13 Blue   NA      NA
    3     1997-04-23 Yellow NA      NA
    3     1997-04-23 Black  NA      NA
    3     1997-04-23 Green  NA      Green
    4     2020-01-27 Red    NA      NA
    4     2020-01-27 Blue   NA      NA 
    5     1999-08-03 Red    NA      NA
    5     1999-08-03 Blue   NA      Yellow
```

For ID with multiple rows I like to retain only rows where values in `Col2` is equal to values in `Col4`. If the ID has multiple rows and the values in `Col2` is NOT equal to values in `Col4` then filter is not applicable. Expecting a final dataset like this below

```
   Id    Date       Col2   Col3    Col4
    1     2011-09-08 Red    NA      NA
    2     2010-07-13 Blue   NA      NA
    
    3     1997-04-23 Green  NA      Green
    
    4     2020-01-27 Red    NA      NA
    4     2020-01-27 Blue   NA      NA 
    5     1999-08-03 Red    NA      NA
    5     1999-08-03 Blue   NA      Yellow
```

What I did so far is this

```
    df_final <- df1 %>% 
                group_by(ID)
                filter(Col2 == Col4, negate(is.na))
```

but this is not working , any suggestions regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and please clarify if you want to compare col2 with col3 (your text) or col2 with col4 (your code). Also you say that your filter should be used when there are multiple IDs, but why do you keep e.g. ID 4 or 5. In none of them does Col2 match Col3 (or Col4).

Comment: @deschen, Col2 vs Col4, thanks for pointing that mistake, I have updated my question now.

Comment: Please still provide a reproducible example, with e.g. dput(YOUR DATA) and clarify on the rationale why you keep both IDs when ID is 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dplyr::filter` joins multiple statements using `&`, that's not what we want, and not sure what you're trying to do with `negate(is.na)` anyway. However, we can do a comparison to see if `Col2 == Col4` and if not, check for the entire group that in no rows that occurs. When doing the comparison, I've just replaced `NA` values in `Col4` with `""` so the comparison returns `T` and `F`, but you can also add in a more complex check for if either are `NA`.

I also created the column to filter on separately to avoid comparing between the columns twice in a single `filter` call.

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(check = Col2 == replace_na(Col4, "")) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  filter(check | !any(check))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#> # Groups:   Id [5]
#>      Id Date       Col2  Col3  Col4   check
#>   <dbl> <date>     <chr> <lgl> <chr>  <lgl>
#> 1     1 2011-09-08 Red   NA    <NA>   FALSE
#> 2     2 2010-07-13 Blue  NA    <NA>   FALSE
#> 3     3 1997-04-23 Green NA    Green  TRUE 
#> 4     4 2020-01-27 Red   NA    <NA>   FALSE
#> 5     4 2020-01-27 Blue  NA    <NA>   FALSE
#> 6     5 1999-08-03 Red   NA    <NA>   FALSE
#> 7     5 1999-08-03 Blue  NA    Yellow FALSE
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), Date = structure(c(15225, 
14803, 9974, 9974, 9974, 18288, 18288, 10806, 10806), class = "Date"), 
    Col2 = c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Black", "Green", "Red", 
    "Blue", "Red", "Blue"), Col3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Col4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Green", NA, NA, NA, 
    "Yellow")), problems = structure(list(row = 7L, col = NA_character_, 
    expected = "5 columns", actual = "6 columns", file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Date = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), Col2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Col3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), Col4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: that is perfect. Thanks.